# Catch Duplicate Key Error in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, duplicates, key

I have this code and I want to add duplication error catch in it, how can I?

```
if (!$row_id) {
    // insert a new
    if ($wpdb->insert($table_name, $args)) {
        return $wpdb->insert_id;
    }
} else {
    // do update method here
    if ($wpdb->update($table_name, $args, array('id' => $row_id))) {
        return $row_id;
    }
}
```

Comment: your else statement is making an update of existant data in DB... what else do you want to do on duplicate key ?

Comment: I want an IF inside an IF so that a duplicate error can be caught. In fact, in both IF and ELSE.

Comment: There can't be a duplicate error... that's what your actual "if else" stands for. If the row already exists, you do an update. So there won't be a duplicate key. So what do you mean by "catch a duplicate error" ? If you don't want an update on duplicate key, do whatever you wish in the "else" statement... If with this code you get a duplicate key error, this means your `$rox_id` is not filled properly. How is it filled ?

Comment: Thanks, I may be wrong in explaining then. Let me make it simple. How can I catch duplicate error this the following code. Disregard the above code. if ($wpdb->insert($table_name, $args)) {
        return $wpdb->insert_id;
    }

Comment: If there is an error, it returns `false`. If you want to display this error, you should have a look [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Show_and_Hide_SQL_Errors)

Comment: OK, let me make it even simpler. I want to convert the following PHP code to WP code. if (mysql_errno() > 0) {
    if (mysql_errno() == 1062) {
        echo "DUPLICATE";
    } else {
        echo "DATABASE ERROR";
    }
} else {
    echo mysql_insert_id();
}

Comment: So you may have to check for `$wpdb->last_error` value... you'll have to check the content of this attribute manually I guess...

Comment: OK, I am almost there, but is there a way to catch error number in WP? Is there a way to catch duplication error code and not the text as in last_error?

Comment: I don't think so. But once again, to catch a duplicate key, all you have to do is a select query right before your insert, and check the number of results. if there are results, you must not insert, and then display the error message you wish...